# Powerpivot with SSAS cube

Tags: mdx, powerpivot

We have an SSAS cube for our patient data. Instead of recreating the entire cube in powerpivot with all the measures and calculations, I am looking to use the cube itself and add onto it. I am just getting familiar with MDX, but is there an easy way to select ALL (select *) for a cube? I really don't want to filter out anything. I can build this with the design view in powerpivot, but as expected it takes forever to build as we have quite a few dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

The MDX to select all would be

```
SELECT FROM [YourCubeName]
```

This query has a zero dimensional result (i. e. one cell, no columns or row axis). And as MDX always aggregates data, this would show you the sum of the default measure across all bottom level data.

If, actually, you want to have all data contained in the cube at leaf level, you would use a query like this, using the [`LEAVES` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144804.aspx), which returns a cross join of the lowest level of all attribute hierarchies in the cube:

```
SELECT Measures.Members
       ON COLUMNS,
       LEAVES()
       ON ROWS
  FROM [YourCubeName]
```

However, MDX/SSAS is not optimized for this type of huge result sets. It is more suited to result sets of a size that is not much more than what fits on a single screen, as it is targeted at online analysis. It may be more efficient to access the underlying relational data from which the cube is built.

Comment: I actually want all the dimensions as well as the measures.  I basically want the cube, but flattened out.

Comment: @SarahBroaden OK, did not understand that initially. I edited my answer.

Comment: Ok, this helps, thanks for submitting. I am new to the cube concept and the problem that we have is that some of the calculations are done inside the cube and not in the underlying data so I didn't want to have to bring in the underlying data and redo all those calculations again in powerpivot but it sounds like that might be the better option.

Comment: @SarahBroaden If you need calculated members as well, then change `Measures.Members` (which only returns the physical, i. e. non calculated measures) to `Measures.AllMembers` (which returns physical and calculated measures). You should be aware however that many calculations cannot be summed up from the leaf data. These are typically measures like growth or share, where the division is done **after** summing. You will have to replicate these anyway in any solution that does not rely on the cube for all aggregations.